# How to mock ICorrelationContextAccessor for CorrelationId

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq, correlation, xunit

For the mocking, I am using Moq 4.16.1 package.

I have a class that derives from DelegatingHandler class

```
public class Handler : DelegatingHandler
{
  private readonly ICorrelationContextAccessor _correlationContextAccessor;
  public Handler(ICorrelationContextAccessor correlationContextAccessor)
        {
            _correlationContextAccessor = correlationContextAccessor;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken ct)
        {
                request.Headers.Add("x-correlation-Id", _correlationContextAccessor.CorrelationContext.CorrelationId);

                var response = await base.SendAsync(request, ct);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                return response;
        }
}
```

now I need to mock the ICorrelationContextAccessor.

I have tried the below code but had no luck

```
_correlationContextAccessor.SetupProperty(x => x.CorrelationContext.CorrelationId, new Guid().ToString());
```

Anyone who how to mock CorrelationId in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code of [CorrelationContext](https://github.com/stevejgordon/CorrelationId/blob/c4e24b5e3c82703492786eecf0b7802828abf339/src/CorrelationId/CorrelationContext.cs#L36), you can't mock `CorrelationId` property because it's an only read property.

There is another way you can try to use it, Try to use mock CorrelationContext property by `SetupProperty` method, then create an instance with your expectation `Guid`

```
var guid = new Guid().ToString();
_correlationContextAccessor.SetupProperty(x => x.CorrelationContext, new CorrelationContext(guid,"x-correlation-Id"));
```

Comment: [Here is a related sample project](https://github.com/stevejgordon/CorrelationId/blob/main/samples/3.1/MvcSampleTests/ServiceWhichUsesCorrelationContextTests.cs) by the library author.